# What issues does the following Distributed Shamir Secret Sharing scheme have?

Tags: public-key, secret-sharing, commitments, voting

What (obvious) security issues does the following "onion" Distributed Shamir Secret Sharing scheme on a blockchain for the purpose of e-voting have?

The blockchain in this context, is an immutable ledger of records, where any known identity can add a record. Authenticity of source of the records, the privacy of the voters, or secrecy of the votes past the election is out of context of this question. Votes need to be hidden only during the election process.

The protocol goes the following way:

1. **Register phase**

Each voter generates it's own SSS secret S and registers itself, by publishing a public key PK, splits S into number of shares N of previous registrees, and encrypts these shares with previous registrees' public keys.

```
register(PK1)
register(PK2, PK1.encrypt(S2share1))
register(PK3, PK2.encrypt(S3share1), PK1.encrypt(S3share2))
register(PK4, PK3.encrypt(S4share1), PK2.encrypt(S4share2), PK1.encrypt(S4share3))
....
register(PKN, PKN-1...PK1.encrypt(shares...))
```

The first registree has a one share to anyone else, the second one has a share to anyone except first, and the last registree has no access to anyones shares.

2. **Voting**

The voting is the process of publishing an encrypted a vote of a registree with key S, along with public disclosure of known shares.

```
vote(S1.encrypt(0), S2share1, S3share2, S4share3)
vote(S2.encrypt(1), S3share1, S4share2)
vote(S3.encrypt(1), S4share1)
vote(1) # unencrypted because no shares could be known
```

As registrees vote, they disclose more and more shares, eventually exceeding the threshold of shares publicly disclosed for certain votes, thus decrypting the votes publicly. As certain threshold of votes gets decrypted, after the deadline, the tally is finilized. If not enough of votes cooperated, the voting is pronounced failed.

I am exploring ways to attack this protocol, like voters intentionally publishing messed up shares, or registries encrypting garbage, but broken share(s) could be treated as no share, and with half the threshold we could afford as many as half messed up shares.

Obviously, a better alternative is a third step with voting split into commitmemt/reveal scheme, but that requires two interactions on the voting process.

Comment: What is the purpose of secret sharing in this scheme?

Comment: @JAAAY to postpone the decryption of the votes until enough of the votes has been collected. The voters that vote majority win points, so there's incentive see what's been voted before and vote just that. I want to get around that problem and only decrypt when the majority of voters have voted. I don't care about vote secrecy past that point otherwise.